# Android Process and Resource managment

Tags: android, service

As Per My Knowledge, In Android when Application is start , Os assign new process to app and app will running in that UIThread (mainthead) of that process.
so operation which is define under Activity Class will run on UiThread ( if we will not create separate class for any operation). and if we perform long running process we will do that task under the Service class ( Service is running even App will kill ).. So Service is running on UiThread or separate Thead? if it runs under UiThread then Why it is not affect to Ui  OR if it runs under separate Thread then why we are creating another separate thread in service for long running operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Android when Application is start , Os assign new process to app

Correct.

> app will running in that UIThread (mainthead) of that process

Incorrect. An "app" does not run on any thread. Methods of Java objects are called on threads.

> so operation which is define under Activity Class will run on UiThread

Incorrect. A Java class does not run on any thread. Methods of Java objects are called on threads. Hence, methods of an activity will be called on threads. Some of those methods will be called on the main application thread (a.k.a., UI thread) of the Android app's process.

> So Service is running on UiThread or separate Thead?

Neither, or both, depending upon how you want to look at it. Again, a Java class does not run on any thread. Methods of Java objects are called on threads. The lifecycle methods of a service (e.g., `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, `onDestroy()`) are called on the main application thread. `onHandleIntent()` of an `IntentService` is called on a background thread.

> if it runs under UiThread then Why it is not affect to Ui

Any time you spend in your code on the main application thread will freeze the UI. It does not matter whether the code is a method on an activity, a method on a service, or a method on something else.

> if it runs under separate Thread then why we are creating another separate thread in service for long running operations?

To avoid tying up the main application thread and thereby freezing the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Services runs on UI thread. Also in some way it can interact with UI.
Here is a good starting article.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: then why it does not block operaion of Ui while Service is running?

Comment: Try to call Thread.sleep() in Service.onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) and you will see that this function blocks UI thread.